# Save Image into sql server or inside the folder name Images in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I have one save button which will save the image in the desktop from camera when button is click below is the code.....

```
<input id="Save" style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 8px; WIDTH: 128px; TOP: 36px; HEIGHT: 24px"
                                        onclick="return save_onclick()" type="button" value="Save Image" name="save">

function save_onclick()
{
    document.AxuEyeCam.SaveImage("test.jpg");       
}
```

It not good to save image in one pc because the image will not be available worldwide,
it will be available for only to the pc which has image.

what i think is to save image in web application using mappath or store image in sql server or may be in cloud so that image will be available worldwide.

Can anybody suggest me how this is possible.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Steps

1- Create a web service and host it in a server ( the web service will contain a web method to upload your file and save it to a server)

2- Call the web service from your application ( Desktop application or web application )

Here is a Good Example for the web service and the client application

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx

I don't recommend saving the image as binary in the database because you may find it harder to retrieve and display

I do recommend saving the file name in the sql server table and save the image itself to a separate folder in your server

Comment: that good idea but how to save the image into web application folder...can you give me the code....thanks

Comment: the following link contains a full code of the web service that save your image to a folder in the server . it also include an application to call the web service save method

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using javascript to save the image, what control are you using to store the image? i.e. what is the AxeEyeCam control you have?

If you can access this control from the Server-Side code then you should be able to read the image into a byte array and save this into SQL.

The following code uses a `FileUpload` control to read the data into a byte array

```
byte[] bArray = new byte[fileUpImage.FileBytes().Length + 1];
int iBytesRead = fileUpImage.FileContent().Read(bArray, 0, fileUpImage.FileBytes().Length);
```

The following code then inserts this into a SQL table called `TABLE` :

```
try {
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(localConString);
    conn.Open();
    string insertStatement = "Insert Into [TABLE] ([IMAGE COLUMN]) VALUES (@Image)";

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(insertStatement, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
    cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = bArray;
    double rdr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
//Catches an error if one occurs

} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        NewConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i am currently using javascript.....axeeyecam is the name of the camera which is used as object....the code below you can see

Comment: <object id="AxuEyeCam" style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 144px; WIDTH: 480px; HEIGHT: 360px"
                                    type="application/activeX-control" height="360" width="480" border="0" classid="CLSID:A88F30FE-4C03-4E37-B6E4-ED9341093780"
                                    name="AxuEyeCam" progid="AxuEyeCam" viewastext></object>

Comment: You may have trouble with saving the image, have you read any of the documentation you got with the item? I'm assuming it is a 3rd party piece of hardware/software?

Comment: i dont have any problem in saving the image...when i click on save image button it is saving the image into the desktop now what my question is to take the save image into the web application folder eg. images folder and then save the path or image into the sql server...am i correct?